# How to change keyboard layout for buildroot?

Tags: keyboard, x86-64, qemu, buildroot, busybox

I'm trying to change the keyboard layout (that is in us) to Spanish when launching the image with qemu.

Should I change something in the output folder, or is there an option when configuring the image I want to create?

Thank you very much.

Im using an x86_64 architecture with busybox and uclib.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dumpkmap > host_layout` in your host machine. (you need busybox installed in your host). This copies the layout of the machine in a binary file.
Then, in the target device, use `loadkmap < host_layout`. Pass the file to QEMU with an usb.
(I used this solution in a raspberrypi arm, but if you're using busybox, it should work)